# Computing capability of GTX 870M

Tags: tensorflow

I was trying to run tensorflow-gpu on an ASUS laptop with a GTX 870M card on Ubuntu 16.40, but got an error message

018-10-07 16:54:50.537324: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1482] Ignoring visible gpu device (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 870M, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 3.0) with Cuda compute capability 3.0. The minimum required Cuda capability is 3.5.

However, GTX 870M's computing capability is listed as 5.0 (Maxwell).  My questions are (1) what is GTX 870M's computing capability, and (2) Can I run tensorflow-gpu (latest or nightly) with GTX 870M?  Thanks, CC.

Comment: Try to post this question in another forum. E.g. SuperUser

Answer (score -2):

I have a Razer Blade 14 2014 with the same GPU on Windows and run on the same problems. Unfortunately the CUDA compute capability [is listed as 3.0](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus) for this GPU.

In the context on Linux you have an advantage, for computing capability of 3.0 you can build the code from source using the official instructions, they recommend docker when doing this: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source

A post I found a post where [the problem is solved](http://www.programmersought.com/article/1316940889/) can help as well.

Please let me know if you could make it work, I will try to install it using latest stable [Ubuntu Mate 18.04.2 LTS](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/).